# Añadir variable en session con jquery o javascript en Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Tengo un proyecto `laravel` y quisiera añadir unos valores en `session` cuando se cambie el valor de un input select por lo que tengo que hacerlo con `javascript` o `jquery` ¿que me recomendáis, hacerlo con un `ajax` de la siguiente manera o hay alguna forma mejor o más limpia?

```
Route::post('/ajax/add-book', function(){
     Session::put( 'bookId', Input::get('bookId') );
});

$('a[data-book]').click(function($e){
    $e.preventDefault();
     $.post("/ajax/add-book", {
        "bookId": $(this).data('book')
      });
});
```

Por otro lado como uso la `session` en una `view`? Hago un **Session::has('param')** o un **Session::get('param')** y no me reconoce `session` y si importo el **facades** no reconoce el **has** o el **get**, alguien sabría decirme que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Está perfecto por lo que yo conozco de laravel. AJAX y `Session::put` es la manera correcta.

Comment: Podrías agregar una verificación en el request para que solo acepte solicitudes ajax, si es el caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer el set ya lo haces bien, utilizando `AJAX` y el `Session::put`:

```
Route::post('/ajax/add-book', function(){
     Session::put( 'bookId', Input::get('bookId') );
});

$('a[data-book]').click(function($e){
    $e.preventDefault();
     $.post("/ajax/add-book", {
        "bookId": $(this).data('book')
      });
});
```

Para el get que te falta. El `route`:

```
Route::get('/ajax/get-book', function()
{
    return Session::get('bookId');
});
```

Y lo llamas des de la función que necesites:

```
//Función que llame
    function(){
        $.get( "ajax/get-book", function( data ) {
             element.innerHTML = data;
        });
    }
```